# How can I create a smart playlist on Apple Music of my instrumental songs (no lyrics)?

Tags: music, apple-music, playlist, smart-playlist, lyrics

I'm looking to create a smart playlist on Apple Music that automatically creates a playlist or finds all of the songs in my library without lyrics. Is there a way to filter songs that Apple Music hasn't assigned lyrics to yet? My initial idea was to curate this list and then manually sift through to weed out tracks that simply lack assigned lyrics but aren't truly instrumental. I'm aware there are scripts for songs with custom lyrics, but I haven't added custom lyrics or descriptions to any of my tracks. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the goal here: Create a smart playlist of all tracks which don’t have lyrics, or of all tracks which are only instrumental?

Comment: @nohillside I would like to make a playlist of all the songs in my library that are instrumental. I was thinking that a way to achieve this might involve looking for songs without lyrics, but I am unsure if that is the best way to go.

Comment: Not sure about the lyrics approach, there are usually songs (where somebody sings) without available lyrics. And I would be surprised if Apple Music provides a way to identify pure instrumental tracks directly.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I was hoping that the lyrics approach would be able to narrow my library down a bit. Do you have any other ideas? @nohillside

Comment: I stopped using iTunes/Music years ago. AFAIR you could filter for tracks without lyrics in the past, but this was removed when the whole cloud part was introduced.